# how to install rpm package to non-default path?

Tags: rpm, system-administration

i have a rpm package, and i need to extract some files from it. The package is not relocatable, i have try "rpm --root/--prefix", which doesn't work.
what methods i should take to do the extraction?

Thank In Advace.

Comment: You would probably get a better answer if you asked this on superuser.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if You need to extract some file only, use this commands:

```
rpm2cpio rpmfile.rpm | cpio -idmv
```