# Precompiled Binaries for GIT

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to install git on a redhat linux box but get the following error because C compilers are against the security policy where I work.

```
configure: Setting lib to 'lib' (the default)
configure: Will try -pthread then -lpthread to enable POSIX Threads.
configure: CHECKS for site configuration
configure: CHECKS for programs
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: in `/home//git-1.9.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Does any one know where I can get the precompiled binaries for Git 1.9.2? Having looked on the net i could not find any. If there are not any how do you install git without having a C compiler

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git ?

Comment: From your linux distribution's Package Manager or PPA. For Windows, there is msysgit with installer

Comment: I am not aware of any repositories that provide such a new Git for Red Hat. In the past, I have dealt with similar situations by [building an RPM](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) on a machine where C compilers are permitted and then installing that RPM on the target box.

Comment: Maybe this answer on ServerFault is useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/81362/how-to-install-git-to-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5-3-x64

Answer (score 1):

On a redHat, I prefer using a search engine like http://rpm.pbone.net, where you can:

- select the target architecture (like "`RedHat EL 7`")
- enter '`git-core`'

I can easily get an rpm relatively recent ([Git 2.19 for instance](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/54523126/dir/redhat_el_7/com/dba-git-2191-2.19.1-8.1.x86_64.rpm.html)), and [using rpm2io/cpio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787544/6309), I can extract/"install" it anywhere I want for testing.